# c# I need help inserting text into the code generated for a linkbutton in a gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, linkbutton

Here is the .aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLeads" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsAdminLeads" AllowSorting="True" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" DataKeyNames="leadKey" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvLeads_selected" OnRowCommand="gvLeads_RowCommand" OnDataBound="gvLeads_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="Edit" ButtonType="Link" />
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Details" Text="Details" /> 
    ...(other BoundFields)
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This generates the following when the page renders:

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Select$0')">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Details$0')">Details</a></td>
...
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Select$1')">Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Details$1')">Details</a></td>
...
```

The page designer would like me to put a div tag between the td and anchor tag so that the resulting html that gets generated will be:

```
<td><div class=editPanel id=edit0></div><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Select$0')">Edit</a></td>
<td><div class=detailPanel id=detail0></div><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Details$0')">Details</a></td>
...
<td><div class=editPanel id=edit1></div><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Select$1')">Edit</a></td>
<td><div class=detailPanel id=detail1></div><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Details$1')">Details</a></td>
...
```

I've tried putting this code in the gvLeads_DataBound function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvLeads.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ((LinkButton)gvLeads.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "<div class=editPanel id=edit" + i + "></div>" + ((LinkButton)gvLeads.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
    ((LinkButton)gvLeads.Rows[i].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = "<div class=detailPanel id=detail" + i + "></div>" + ((LinkButton)gvLeads.Rows[i].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
}
```

But this results in the  tags being put inside the anchor tag as such:

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Select$0')"><div class=editPanel id=edit0></div>Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Details$0')"><div class=detailPanel id=detail0></div>Details</a></td>
...
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Select$1')"><div class=editPanel id=edit1></div>Edit</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ucLeads$gvLeads','Details$1')"><div class=detailPanel id=detail1></div>Details</a></td>
```

So the .Text property of the LinkButton control is not what I need, but I don't know what property of what control in the cell to use to put the div text where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

In your columns tag, you can use ItemTemplate tag to combine multiple items into one column.  I think that should do what you need.

I believe it will require you to mark the divs with the runat attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `LiteralControl` of a div at the start of the cells control collection should do it.

```
gvLeads.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls.AddAt(0, 
      new LiteralControl("<div class=editPanel id=edit" + i + "></div>"));
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Thank you so much.  One thing... there needs to be one more closing parenthesis before the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

In your Databound

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl("<div class=editPanel id=edit" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "><div>"));
e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl("<div class=detailPanel id=detail" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "><div>"));
```